# Retrive values of array from wp_option table of wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, oop

I added some value in associative array into wp_option table of wordpress. The result is given below.

```
  array($computer=>$mouse, $mouse=>$keyboard);
  get_option( 'policy_number' );
```

Output :

```
  Array
  (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [comoputer1] => mousevalue
            [mousevalue] => keyboardvalue
        )
  )
```

How can i retrieve value of **mousevalue** ? Which is **keyboardvalue**.

Comment: $array[$array['computer1']]

Comment: Dennis please check again question..thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 1):

You have an array within an array. You want the first item (index 0) of the parent array, and you want to return a `value` by its `key`:

```
$values = get_option( 'policy_number' );

foreach ($values as $value) {
    echo $value['mousevalue'];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but my all key are stored in $abc[$key] how can i use $abc[$key]  instead of ['mouevalue'] ? Please suggest me.

Comment: When i write echo $abc[$key]; then it returns the value of array

Comment: I don't understand...did you not want the value of `'mousevalue'`?

Comment: Everything working fine with this below code. But it prints only static array. I would like to get value as dynamic using loop. my code is : $tmp = $abc[$key]; echo $dis[0][$tmp]; here insetad of 0 it my be anything like $dis[45][$tmp]. how can i do this?

Comment: Yes! it's working. Some little changes needed here. it prints repeated same value. for ex, output is : abc abc abc abc . I want only "abc"  as output only once not repeated. But it must be in loop.